# function range of $h(x) = 4 − x^2$ in textbook seems have error

Tags: calculus

I'm reading a book, named *Calculus* 12th edition be written by Ron Larson and Bruce Edwards.

In P3 exercise 15th at textbook P27:

Find the Domain and Range of  Function
$h(x)=4-x^2$

Answer given in the text book is:
Domain: $(-\infty, \infty)$: Range: $(-\infty, \infty)$

I think answer of 15th exercise have error, but I not find errata of this book.

I think domain of $h(x) = 4 − x^2$ is domain: $(−\infty, \infty)$ that it's right.

But it seems that range of $h(x) = 4 − x^2$ should be range: $(−\infty, 4]$ rather than range: $(−\infty, \infty)$.

So is the answer to question 15 incorrect?

Comment: Your answer is right. may be a typo in answer key?

Comment: I agree with @coffeemath. Your answer is right and most likely this is an error/typo in the solutions of the book.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you for your reply. I know.

Comment: @xyz Thank you for your reply. I know.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Perhaps you could see if there is an errata sheet for that book.  Perhaps on the publisher's web page.  Or the author's.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for the link that you provide.

Comment: @GEdgar When I Google with `calculus ron larson 12th edition errata` but not find errata of this book and on the publisher's web page or the author's web page also not find errata of this book. Can you help me to find the errata of this book? Thank you.